# simultaneous read on file descriptor from two threads

Tags: multithreading, posix, file-descriptor

1. **my question**: in Linux (and in FreeBsd, and generally in UNIX) is it possible/legal to read single file descriptor simultaneously from two threads?
2. I did some search but found nothing, although a lot of people ask like question about reading/writing from/to socket fd at the same time (meaning reading when other thread is writing, not reading when other is reading). I also have read some man pages and got no clear answer on my question.
3. Why I ask it. I tried to implement simple program that counts lines in stdin, like wc -l. I actually was testing my home-made C++ io engine for overhead, and discovered that wc is 1.7 times faster. I trimmed down some C++ and came closer to wc speed but didn't reach it. Then I experimented with input buffer size, optimized it, but still wc is clearly a bit faster. Finally I created 2 threads which read same STDIN_FILENO in parallel, and this at last was faster than wc! But lines count became incorrect... so I suppose some junk comes from reads which is unexpected. Doesn't kernel care what process read?

Edit: I did some research and discovered just that calling read directly via syscall does not change anything. Kernel code seem to do some sync handling, but i didnt understand much (read_write.c)

Comment: As an aside:  parallelizing reads is probably going to make you slower rather than faster.  If you have an I/O bottleneck, then all you're doing is creating lock contention.  You might focus instead on your buffering strategy.

Comment: But i do not lock, i just read, the kernel is supposed to lock internally. On buffering: i tried to vary buffer size and came up with some optimum. It is still slower than wc. I now have a theory that i need non-blocking reads to improve performance.

Comment: Non-blocking read also does not help. hmm..

Comment: non-blocking read + buffer size of 8 pages + std::count finally beats wc -l. Never mind, that was not exactly my question.

Comment: 2 threads with proper locking are 20% faster than best single-threaded version. No use to test more threads as i have only 2 cores.

Comment: Can we make it more clear that this question and some answers are strictly about `pipe, FIFO, or terminal device` and the answers may be different for regular files?

Answer (score 6):

That's undefined behavior, [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html)
says:

> The read() function shall attempt to read nbyte bytes from the file
> associated with the open file descriptor, fildes, into the buffer
> pointed to by buf. The behavior of multiple concurrent reads on the
> same pipe, FIFO, or terminal device is unspecified.

Comment: POSIX will have to be defined by observation, per OS. I see more of such bold concurrent reading discoverers coming :) with the rise of SSDs where I/O is not the bottleneck anymore (or at least not by such margin)

Comment: However, the behavior of `read()` on regular files and symlinks _is_ defined. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

About accessing a single file descriptor concurrently (i.e. from multiple threads or even processes), I'm going to cite [POSIX.1-2008 (IEEE Std 1003.1-2008), Subsection *2.9.7 Thread Interactions with Regular File Operations*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_07):

> 2.9.7 Thread Interactions with Regular File Operations
>
> All of the following functions shall be atomic with respect to each other in the effects specified in POSIX.1-2008 when they operate on regular files or symbolic links:
>
> […] read() […]
>
> If two threads each call one of these functions, each call shall either see all of the specified effects of the other call, or none of them. […]

At first glance, this looks quite good. However, I hope you did not miss the restriction *when they operate on regular files or symbolic links*.

@jarero cites:

> The behavior of multiple concurrent reads on the same pipe, FIFO, or terminal device is unspecified.

So, implicitly, we're agreeing, I assume: It depends on the type of the file you are reading. You said, you read from STDIN. Well, if your STDIN is a plain file, you can use concurrent access. Otherwise you shouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

When used with a descriptor (fd), read() and write() rely on the internal state of the fd to know the "current offset" at which the read and write will occur.  As a result, they aren't thread-safe.

To allow a single descriptor to be used by multiple threads simultaneously, pread() and pwrite() are provided.  With those interfaces, the descriptor and the desired offset are specified, so the "current offset" in the descriptor isn't used.