# multiple threads reading a file: pread or multiple fds

Tags: c, multithreading, performance

I have a multi-threaded program and I want to have each thread read from the same file and have the same data

I know that from `pread(2)` it is thread safe; however, I'm concerned about speed and not memory.

Will it be faster to have multiple threads read from the same file descriptor using `pread` or would it be faster for each individual thread to have its own file descriptor to the same file and read from there?

My thought is, if `pread` is atomic, then that prevents another thread from reading at the same time; however, if having *lots* of threads each with their own fd and the OS needs to service each read, then all that context switching might take up more time.

Comment: As with any other performance question the thing to do is profile and measure the two approaches to compare. That is the best way too answer your own question.

Comment: @kaylum would I want to use something like gprof or something like valgrind or would they basically be doing the same thing?

Comment: Presumably the file is rather large, and the different threads do different processing on the data.  Kernel buffer pools will keep the disk blocks in memory so that when one thread reads a block from disk, other threads will benefit from the block already being in the kernel buffer pool (unless there's too much memory pressure and/or disk activity).  You are probably really only concerned with the overall time for the process; you could probably get away with a crude measurement of elapsed time processing the file.

Comment: My best guess is that there won't be a lot of difference between multiple `open()` calls and multiple `pread()` calls.  If anything, the multiple file descriptors will simplify the code (less chance to get the positioning wrong), so you'll win that way.  But if you're really concerned, measurement is the only way to get a decent answer, but remember that the answer may be different on different hardware.  There's no significant difference in terms of context switches; the `read()` and `pread()` calls both require context switches.

Comment: Does the file fit into RAM?  How long does your processing run?  This is actually one of the best use-cases for `mmap()`, especially if the file fits into RAM and the processing is both long-running and read-intensive.  Between `read()` on multiple descriptors and `pread()` on one descriptor, `read()` requires an `lseek()` to set the position, and that also incurs a context switch. On Linux, both `pread()` and `read()` quickly reach `vfs_read()`, but `read()` also requires reading and then setting the file position too. See http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/read_write.c#L584

Comment: @SailorCire, did you manage to find a solution to your question ? I have the same requirement and a perf test shows that pread is faster than read (for reading). But it slows down write operation.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057737/simultaneous-read-on-file-descriptor-from-two-threads

Comment: Wy have multiple reads at all? Just have one, and then have the threads process the resulting data. This will be N times as fast in the reading part.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same requirement I did a test for this. According to the test on a SSD and a HDD,
**pread** - improves the read speed, but if same FD is used for the writing, write becomes slow.
**read** (with a separate FD) - read operations are slower compared to pread. But it does NOT impact write operations (done using a separate FD).

So best option is to,

- Use a separate FD for writing (Write Only mode)
- Open a single FD (Read only mode) and use it across multiple threads using pread

---

results on a SSD (read/write count 10,000,000)

| - | pread (same FD used for write and read) | read using a different FD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Read | 25 sec + | 27 sec + |
| Write | 38 sec + | 33 sec+ |

Code used for the test

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <sstream>  

#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <memory>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

off_t tell(int fd)
{
    return lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
}

inline int64_t getMicroSecDiff(const timeval& begin, const timeval& end)
{
    constexpr uint32_t MicroSecPerSec = 1000 * 1000;
    return (end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec) * MicroSecPerSec + (end.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec);
}

inline int64_t getMicroSecDiffFrom(const timeval& begin)
{
    timeval end;
    gettimeofday(&end, nullptr);

    return getMicroSecDiff(begin, end);
}

using namespace std;


int g_fileFd_A = -1;
int g_fileFd_B = -1;

std::atomic<int64_t> g_lastFileAPos = { -1 };
std::atomic<int64_t> g_lastFileBPos = { -1 };

std::atomic<bool> g_writeCompleted = { false };

const int WriteSz = 1;

uint64_t g_writeCount = 0;

void writer(int fdA, int fdB)
{
    timeval begin;
    gettimeofday(&begin, nullptr);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < g_writeCount; i++)
    {
        int64_t fileAPosition = tell(fdA);
        int64_t fileBPosition = tell(fdB);

        auto written = write(fdA, "A", WriteSz);
        assert(written == WriteSz);
        written = write(fdB, "b", WriteSz);
        assert(written == WriteSz);

        g_lastFileAPos.store(fileAPosition, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        g_lastFileBPos.store(fileBPosition, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
    g_writeCompleted = true;

    auto diff = getMicroSecDiffFrom(begin);
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "Write time: " << diff / 1000000 << " sec " << diff % 1000000 << " us" << endl;
    cout << oss.str();

}

void reader(bool duplicateFds)
{
    char bufferA[8];
    char bufferB[8];
    int failedCount = 0;

    int fdA, fdB;
    if (duplicateFds)
    {
        fdA = open("./A", O_RDONLY);
        fdB = open("./B", O_RDONLY);
    }
    else
    {
        fdA = g_fileFd_A;
        fdB = g_fileFd_B;
    }

    timeval begin;
    gettimeofday(&begin, nullptr);
    size_t iteNo = 0;
    //for (; g_writeCompleted.load(memory_order_relaxed) == false; iteNo++)
    for (; iteNo < g_writeCount; iteNo++)
    {
        off_t posA = g_lastFileAPos.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        off_t posB = g_lastFileBPos.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);

        if (posA < 0 or posB < 0)
        {
            iteNo--;
            gettimeofday(&begin, nullptr);
            continue;
        }

        int readSzA;
        int readSzB;

        off_t readPosA = rand();
        off_t readPosB = rand();

        if (readPosA > posA)
        {
            readPosA = posA;
        }

        if (readPosB > posB)
        {
            readPosB = posB;
        }
                
        if (duplicateFds)
        {
            lseek(fdA, readPosA, SEEK_SET);
            lseek(fdB, readPosB, SEEK_SET);

            readSzA = read(fdA, bufferA, WriteSz);
            readSzB = read(fdB, bufferB, WriteSz);
        }
        else
        {
            readSzA = pread(fdA, bufferA, WriteSz, readPosA);
            readSzB = pread(fdB, bufferB, WriteSz, readPosB);
        }

        if (readSzA < WriteSz or readSzB < WriteSz)
        {
            failedCount++;

            if (failedCount % 1000 == 0)
            {
                cout << " " << failedCount;
                cout.flush();
            }
        }
    }

    auto diff = getMicroSecDiffFrom(begin);
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "Read time: " << diff / 1000000 << " sec " << diff % 1000000 << " us"  << " ReadCount=" << iteNo << endl;
    oss << "failedCount=" << failedCount << endl;
    cout << oss.str();

    if (duplicateFds)
    {
        close(fdA);
        close(fdB);
    }
}



int main (int argc, char** argv) 
{
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " duplicateFds" << " write-count" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    bool duplicateFds = atoi(argv[1]);
    g_writeCount = atoi(argv[2]);
    cout << "duplicateFds=" << duplicateFds << " write-count=" << g_writeCount << endl;

    if (duplicateFds)
    {
        g_fileFd_A = open("./A", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
        g_fileFd_B = open("./B", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
    }
    else 
    {
        g_fileFd_A = open("./A", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
        g_fileFd_B = open("./B", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
    }

    std::thread readerThread1(reader, duplicateFds);
    std::thread readerThread2(reader, duplicateFds);
    std::thread writerThread(writer, g_fileFd_A, g_fileFd_B);

    readerThread1.join();
    readerThread2.join();
    writerThread.join();

    close(g_fileFd_A);
    close(g_fileFd_B);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would be useful to see your test code here and numbers from tests rather than expecting us to take it at face value.

Comment: There is, you can do it in the markdown or with the button in the editor.